# JupyterLab error messages when shutting down kernel with TensorFlow scripts

Tags: conda, tensorflow2.0, jupyter-lab

I just set up a new workstation with miniconda and TensorFlow 2.5. The JupyterLab version is 3.1.17. When I shut down a kernel with TensorFlow Python scripts, it would generate the following error messages:

[image: Wnter image description here]

If I shut down a kernel that does not have TensorFlow, there isn't any error message. How can I fix it?

[Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) list output for selected packages:

[image]

I reinstalled *tensorflow/tensorflow-gpu* and the revised Conda list output is:

[image]

Comment: Not saying this is *the* problem, but the mix of Conda `tensorflow=2.5.0` and Pip `tensorflow-gpu==2.6.0` doesn't inspire confidence.

Comment: Note that conda tensorflow-gpu has v2.5.0, while pip tensorflow-gpu has v2.6.0. Per Anaconda documentation, it is okay to use conda to install the base packages and then use pip to install additional packages that are not in conda channels.

Comment: I think both the version mixing (2.5.0 and 2.6.0) and channel mixing are potentially problematic because `tensorflow-gpu` is the *implementation backend* of `tensorflow`.

Comment: Instead of screenshots, please provide the corresponding text. Thanks in advance. But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like installed versions of miniconda,tensorflow are not compatible.

Check the relevant documentation for right versions and its compatibility.

You must downgrade/upgrade to right version if its not compatible.

- [Tensorflow installation documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)
- [Minicondo reference document](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)